# Noise Reduction in Transformer Circuit

Tags: transformer, noise, schematics, emc

I am using below scheme for generating different voltages using transformer.

[image: Transformer]

T1 transformer generates 15V and 48V ac and then rectified by AC-DC converter to generate different DC voltages (12V_Op amp Supply, -12V_Op amp supply, 16V_Logic, 38V_Constant Current Source) for my circuitry. But transformer is generating noise which is hampering ADC circuit and variation observed in ADC.

What techniques I can ensure to eliminate noise from transformer, please someone guide.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What type of noise? EMI? Acoustic?

Comment: @ Winny, EMI noise.

Comment: This is a sine-output Royer oscillator and shouldn't be a noise on its output. Can you share a scope-measurement? Is that noise audible? An off-chance it might come from switching action.

Comment: Unfortunately, i don't have scope to share waveforms... but noise is not audible... As you said, switching action is there for solenoid valve and relay circuitry.. Is there any precaution i can take in pcb design or any shielding can be used for noise reduction?

Comment: You can start by placing RC snubbers across the transistors' and other switching elements if the noise is some kind of ringing. But you need an oscilloscope because you must first measure the ringing frequency.

Comment: "switching action is there for ***solenoid valve*** and ***relay circuitry***" are you *sure* the noise is from the transformer, and not from the inductive loads you're switching? At a minimum, I hope you have freewheel-diodes placed across those inductive loads to prevent inductive spiking back into the rest of the circuit every time one is deactivated.

Comment: Wow, I missed that "switching action is there for solenoid valve and relay circuitry" statement. As Robherc stated, reverse diodes should be placed across inductive loads. For better noise immunity, make sure you have placed a 0.1-1uF non-polarized capacitor close to the supply pins of ADCs/DACs and other ICs.

Comment: Is it required for solenoid valve also ?

Comment: @Electroholic you might want to check for mutual inductive coupling if the magnetic  components are close together